# Yii2: how to join models?

Tags: php, model, controller, yii2

I have a model called **MovementsSearch.php** with the typical  `search($params)` function that generates the data provider for `actionIndex()` function of the **MovementsController.php**.

**search($params) in MovementsSearch.php:**

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Movements::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id_movement' => $this->id_movement,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

**actionIndex() in MovementsController.php:**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new MovementsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

I need to join all these tables but I can't do it. Maybe it is possible to join the data provider of each model. It will result in a big table with a lot of columns but then I know how to select the columns that I need.

`administrators_offices` and `products_offices` are many-to-many relations.

[image: Database diagram with relationships]

Comment: There are certainly different solutions. One might be to create a database view and query that. You could then use ArrayDataProvider or define a corresponding model and a controller with views. Or you could use the SqlDataProvider.